# How can I cut off tip of a cone?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a cone and I want to cut of top piece of it. How can I make cut face flat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In orthographic mode <kbd>Numpad-5</kbd> invoke the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd>, press <kbd>C</kbd> for angle constrained, and <kbd>Z</kbd> for cut through.
Space or Enter to confirm the cut.

After that you only need to remove the vertex on the tip.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

While this is a duplicate question, I see no answer that deals with using the operator settings to do this in one step. So, one way would be to just add a cone primitive to the scene. *Add > Mesh > Cone* and increase the *Radius 2* slider.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this very simply. Add a cube, and position it above your cone. Then put a *Boolean* modifier on your cone like in the image below, making sure that the *Boolean* modifier is set to *difference*. You can apply the modifier like this, or simply leave it how it is.

[image]