# How to smooth a cone side without changing its shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to smooth cone's side like I did for a cylinder using `Edge Split` and `Subdivision Surface`.

However, the cone (red one) is changing its shape at the top:
[image]
[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You could try adding an edge loop very close to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to actually use a cylinder. you can then shrink the top to a very small size in order to make it feel like a cone. Then add an edge split modifier and the SubSurf. 
The reason a cylinder is better is that the edge split doesn't work really well for triangles, and the cone basemesh is made of triangles. (You can't add edge loops on a cone).

[image: Cylinder-cone trick]

On the screenshot I made the cylinder top big so you can see it's actually a cylinder but feel free to shrink the size as you want.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39289/why-cant-i-loop-cut-a-cone and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35581/how-would-you-make-an-edge-circle-around-a-cone/35582#35582 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23363/how-can-i-cut-off-tip-of-a-cone

Comment: I would like to note that I used `Simple Deform -> Taper` modifier to change the shape of a cylinder.

Comment: I didn't find the modifier you are talking about in the modifiers panel
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**edit** oh sorry actually it is in the modifier panel just didn't understant you had to pick the simple deform modifier with taper option

Answer (score 1):

1. I extrude the bottom ring just a tiny bit like you see on the
   picture.
2. Then I took the original loop above and performed edge slide all the way up to where you see the tiny loop up top.
3. Then I extruded the bottom loop again a tiny bit like the first time.
4. And finally I made the bottom loop completely sharp.

[image: Smooth Cone]